# Reporting Services Report Export to Excel Crashed in My Program

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, reportserver

I have a problem ssrs report export to excel in my application .I taken always this error .I attached picture.How can I solve problem ? I think it can be internet options security settings but I didn't find anything :

[image: Error picture]

[image: error picture2]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser to see if you get the same issue? It might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hi Alan, this report embeded in my program.Reports is working on browser.But I want to use in my program I think some internet options security needed